Why eigenvectors are different although their parametric forms are the same?
Refer to https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/diagonalization.html,
there are two examples as follows
eigenvector calculation in Example (A diagonalizable 2x2 matrix)
eigenvector calculation in Example (A diagonalizable 2x2 matrix with a zero eigenvector)
The question: Why eigenvectors are different although their parametric forms are the same?
Thanks!

Eigenvectors are defined up to multiplicative constant. In other words, (1,-1) and (-1,1) are the same.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The zero vector is never an eigenvector. An eigenvector is defined to be a nonzero vector such that $Av=\lambda v$.

Eigenvectors are not unique notice how in the text it says an eigenvector and not the eigenvector.
